# How do I fix "can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found" on USB boot?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, 11.04

I tried to install Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop using thumb drive, but it failed, even though I used the standard Startup Disk Creator utility.

The laptop is a a Dell Studio 1536.

The problem shows as:

```
stdin: error 0
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found
...
```

What is the problem? What did I do wrong or what's wrong with boot loader?

Comment: Did you setup BIOS to boot from USB-drive?

Comment: Yes I did, I can even select boot device

Comment: I've mounted ISO image from my home directory under the BusyBox shell, so the question is how to start the installation process from this stage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If you got this bug, when you boot from USB, press F6 then edit the boot option:
>
> #### Remove this:
>
> ```
> file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed
> ```
>
> #### Add these:
>
> ```
> live-media-path=/casper/
> ignore_uuid
> ```
>
> #### Full sample:
>
> ```
> append boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz live-media-path=/casper/ quiet splash ignore_uuid --
> ```
>
> If you don't want to edit every time you boot from USB, you can edit this file in USB:
> `/syslinux/text.cfg`

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/492301/comments/17

Comment: Doesn't work, options already present.

Answer (score 15):

I've had the same problem the entire night. It's due to the installer not recognizing the USB drive after it's booted to BusyBox.

To fix this, you need to press F6 and modify the boot options. First, remove "**quiet splash**" from the options and add "**break debug**" in it's place. Continue installation as normal from this point. Eventually, it will break and you'll be presented with the BusyBox shell, and see plenty of the errors relating to this.

Are you ready for the next step? I promise you, it's an advanced manuver that even Han Solo himself would struggle to attempt.

Step 1: **Unplug your USB drive**

Step 2: **Plug your USB drive back in**

Step 3: Type **exit** and press **<Enter>**

Step 4: Wait 5-30 seconds and you'll be booted into your Ubuntu graphical installer.

**Note:** I've verified this works for Ubuntu and Linux Mint. I've been working on this problem for about 4 hours tonight and this is what worked for me, after trying every imaginable method of configuration flags for both the installer and BIOS. I am using a Toshiba Satellite C655D **and** using a 32GB USB 3.0 flash drive as the installation media.

I hope this helps someone, as I was about to go back to Windows after this nightmare.

Comment: Unbelievably this worked for me.  I was shocked.  Thank you so much!

Comment: 2019 checking in. This worked on 18.04.

Comment: Glad to hear I am still relevant!

Comment: I had the same problem trying to boot into live USB Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I can confirm this solution worked like a charm, thanks so much @ITAdminNC ;)

Comment: Worked for me!  In my case, I re-flashed the drive using Etcher between steps 1 and 2, though that likely wasn't necessary.

Comment: Magic!, but for me, I have to edit edit the  boot options through grup(There is no F6 for my case).  I am installing 22.04

Comment: Quickly unplugging and re-plugging the USB device while the `can't open /dev/sr0` message repeats on screen worked for me (22.04)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in [this comment on Launchpad bug 492301](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/492301/comments/17). If you've got this bug, when you boot from USB, press <kbd>F6</kbd> then edit the boot options:

**Add these:**

```
live-media-path=/casper/
ignore_uuid
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be [bug #492301](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/492301)

Try disabling Floppy in BIOS to find out.

Comment: My BIOS doesn't have this option, I don't know to disable this stuff(

Answer (score 1):

Befort the installation it should tell you that there are still some devices mounted. It will ask you to unmount them. **Don't tell it to unmount them** as it will also try to unmount your USB drive, which is the installation medium.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue trying to boot Ubuntu 21.04 live CD on my Acer Swift 5 laptop, and none of the proposed solutions seemed to work.

Reading [ITAdminNC's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/713799/1402838) I realized I was also using a relatively large USB drive (32 GB).

Trying with a smaller drive (16 GB) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

We literally solved the problem by unplugging the USB drive WHILE the installation process was running, and replugging it back in another USB port on the PC.

Comment: This does work. Removed the USB and added to a USB-C port, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Choosing to install with option **Safe Graphics** solves this

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today, while trying out the solution of ITAdminNC I spotted an error message that pointed me to my solution.

It appears that the USB bus cant power the USB Stick sufficiently for some reason. So I disconnected my USB SSD Harddrive and plugged the USB into a different port.

This fixed the issue instantaneously.

(this is the first contribution from a Linux newbie, so please forgive me any errors here)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Solved by moving the usb thumbdrive to a usb port connected directly to the motherboard (back panel) instead of a port on the case and on a hub wich gave me this error.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this was an issue with Legacy boot. I was installing pop os 21.04, and I was using CSM mode. The priority was set to legacy first, and since it is technically bootable in legacy, it booted. That seemed to break the installer, so I changed to UEFI first, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to understand what happened in my case, buh literally pressing the f6 button continually did the trick for me

Running pop os 21.04 Nvidia installer on a 4gb 2.0 flash drive

Answer (score 0):

I have had this strange issue too, when installing dual-boot MacOs and Ubuntu **on an iMac 2012**. Sometimes it occurs, sometimes not.

Try to stop you machine, keep it stopped for 30 seconds, put the USB drive **in another USB slot** and start again. That seems to help.

Success!