# Ubuntu 20.04 installation from USB fails pre-installation

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04

I've acquired the 20.04 ISO via the official torrent and created a bootable USB drive via Rufus 3.11
The drive boots into the GRUB menu where I can select

```
Ubuntu
Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
```

Selecting Ubuntu results in:

```
usb 1-14: device not accepting address 5, error -62
usb 1-14: device not accepting address 6, error -62
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb usb1-port14: unable to enumerate USB device
ln: /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: No such file or directory
stdin: Invalid arguement
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
stdin: Invalid arguement
stdin: Invalid arguement
stdin: Invalid arguement
stdin: Invalid arguement
...
stdin: Invalid arguement
stdin: Invalid arguement
stdin: Invalid arguement
```

Then there is a busybox shell, where if I exit twice I end up with a kernel panic.

What's wrong with this installation? I've redone the whole creating a bootable USB thing multiple times but it has no change.

Comment: "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount." You need to turn fast start up off in Windows.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  Fast Start/Hibernation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  What brand/model system? Sometimes different flash drive, different USB port or different installer make a difference. Make sure you are making an UEFI installer, not CSM (legacy UEFI) which is old BIOS boot mode.

Comment: Fixed by following this post. Any advice involving windows was irrelevant. https://askubuntu.com/a/713799/831111