# Error installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, live-usb

When I plug my flash disk for bootable Ubuntu installer, the result is:

```
/init : line 49: can't open /dev/sr0: No Medium found.
```

[image]

Comment: Your flash disk  is unbootable. There are no bootable devices/partitions. At the end, it's offering to try to boot over the network. Unless network booting is knowledgeably arranged in advance, it's a non-starter. How did you prepare the flash disk?

Comment: There's a problem with your installation media. There are many ways for the creation of installation media to go wrong- usually due to corruption or user error (mistake). To reduce the chance of this happening, I suggest that you re-download the ISO using the BitTorrent link from [alt downloads](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).  Then use [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to flash that ISO to your USB stick. The BT protocol automatically verifies the integrity of downloads. Etcher verifies the integrity of the flash, and is very easy-it doesn't give you "wrong" choices.

Comment: Assuming your on Windows 10, try this guide: Guide: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview Alt Guide: https://linuxconfig.org/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-20-04-usb-stick-on-ms-windows-10

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue just now when tryna install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my desktop. I followed instructions exactly as outlined [in this ubuntu.com tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) using rufus/unetbootin - both failed.

I even tried changing the `text.cfg` file as outlined [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/51350) - nothing worked.

In the end using a USB2.0 usb stick instead of 3.0 did the trick for me. Extremely frustrating experience - hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered with the same issue. I restarted my system numerous times, created a Bootable USB drive numerous times and nothing seemed to work. What solved it for me was simply trying to force the system to go into bios mode (Pressing F2, Lenovo) when the error showed up.

Once this was done the errors went away and I was able to successfully install Ubuntu 20.04 on my old laptop, giving the little work horse at least a few more years of life.

Once again, let me reiterate this worked for me, no promises. I am 100% sure one of you Linux Geniuses can explain in great detail, why the systems falls into this loop. It is at least worth a try. All the Best!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1176649)

Answer (score 0):

When you boot from usb press `F6` then add this

```
append boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz live-media-path=/casper/ quiet splash ignore_uuid --
```

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the almost same error for 2 days, it costs lots of time.
But it was solved like below 2 reasons.

1. It can be caused if you were using wrong USB port of your labtop. So I changed to another USB port of my labtop, then solved. I really don't know what is exaclty wrong but could be USB 3.0 or 2.x.
2. Or if you were using UEFI format while USB image writing, you must change it to the same UEFI format at the bios settings of your labtop, too.

Good luck to you all