# How can I fix “can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found” on USB boot when installing Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, boot-repair, syslinux

When I try to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my *Dell Inspiron 5558* laptop, I get `can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found` error when *GRUB* tries to load *"Install Ubuntu 20.04"*.

I have seen similar kind of problem with *Ubuntu 11.04* in this post: [How do I fix “can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found” on USB boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47076/how-do-i-fix-cant-open-dev-sr0-no-medium-found-on-usb-boot). But that didn't work for *Ubuntu 20.04*: in fact, I tried pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> and my PC automatically checked some information and I was able to install *Ubuntu 20.04* at first. But when I restarted my PC after installing, it still had that booting problem issue and pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> didn't work then. `Also txt.cfg` file of *Ubuntu 20.04* doesn't match with *Ubuntu 11.04*.

I have also tried using other Linux Distro ISO files, re-downloading the ISO files, changing my installation medium (pen drive), changing **BIOS/UEFI boot mode** and also **resetting the CMOS** to hard reset the BIOS, but none of those worked for me and I figured out that the problem is with my ISO file. But, I don't know how to solve this issue.

Previously, I have installed *Ubuntu 18.04* in this same PC without any problem. But suddenly *Ubuntu 18.04* installation also gives the same kind of error message (this also happens with other Linux Distros).

My PC was manufactured with **Ubuntu as default OS**, so I shouldn't get this type of error (but I don't know why I am getting this error). I will have to go back to **Windows** if this issue doesn't get solved because I can install **Windows** on my PC without any problem.

Comment: So you are trying to boot Ubuntu from a USB?

Comment: Yes, I am. What should I do? @SimpliFixed

Comment: How did you create the USB? I would try the Ubuntu guide on creating a bootable ubuntu drive and see if something was perhaps missed or did not work properly when the issue drive was created: Widnows - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview and if you dont have access to Windows I can post a linux guide.

Comment: I have used several softwares for several times from Windows. Such as: Rufus, Etcher, Win32 disk imager. I tested for both Legacy and UEFI mode. @SimpliFixed

Comment: If you can boot from a bootable Windows disk then its either the process or the image is bad so you can download the image again for ubuntu desktop and use the hash to check that it is intact and try creating it again. Have you tried chosing the USB directly in the BIOS and see if it boots then?

Comment: I just checked the hash checksum and it is OK. What advantage will I get if I choose USB directly in the BIOS? @SimpliFixed

Comment: It will always try an inserted USB first before trying anything else, what I am suggestion is with the USB connected go into the BIOS and chose to boot from it during that boot, my BIOS has this option, if you dont then adjust your boot order so it will try the USB before any other device and then move on if you dont have a bootable USB, something is not working right

Comment: Brother, I just chose USB directly in the BIOS but it didn't work. Because the problem occurs when GRUB tries to load Ubuntu and not when BIOS loads GRUB! By the way, thanks a lot for your cooperation, maybe I have just bad luck with my PC! @SimpliFixed